# convert image to byte in react js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, file-upload

I have to upload an image to my backend Spring Boot. I have model object as

```java
class company {
    String name;
    byte[]  logo;
}
```

I need to upload an image from ReactJS, then convert the image to byte and store it in database as bytea in PostgreSQL database.

I have Spring controller as:

```java
@PostMapping("/saveCompany")
public Company createRetailOutletDetails(@RequestBody Company company) throws Exception {
    try {
        return companyServiceImpl.saveCompanyDetails(company);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        throw new Exception(Constants.APP_ERROR, exp);
    }
}
```

My ReactJS code is:

1. convert image to byte array

```js
function readFileDataAsBase64(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                resolve(event.target.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = (err) => {
                reject(err);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    }
```

and save part:

```
const saveCompanyDetails = (e) => {
      var data = {
        name: company.name,
        logo: file
      };
      companyDataService.create(data)
}
```

and service code as

```
const create = (data) => {
    return http.post("/saveCompany", data, {
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
    });
};
```

But I am getting error while binding byte to Spring Boot model object, and getting below error.

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `[B` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[B` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 159] (through reference chain: com.maargali.fuelman.admin.model.Company["logo"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the content type to: `application/json`. As your content type is currently incorrect it cannot deserialize the json you are sending.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).